# Average value of complex exponential

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, cauchy-principal-value

I'm interested in evaluating the following limit
$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T dt\;e^{i(\varepsilon'-\varepsilon)t},$$
with $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon'$ being real numbers. Performing the integral first yields
$$\frac{-i}{\varepsilon'-\varepsilon}\left(e^{i(\varepsilon'-\varepsilon)T}-1\right).$$
Dividing by $T$ and taking the limit, seems to converge to zero. This does not look correct at first glance.

It is suspiciously temping to using the principle value of the exponential as
$$\int_0^\infty dt\;e^{i(\varepsilon'-\varepsilon)t}=\pi\delta(\varepsilon'-\varepsilon)+\frac{i}{\varepsilon'-\varepsilon}$$
Would that be of any use?
Setting $\varepsilon=\varepsilon'$ in the first equation, the limit evaluates to 1, hinting at the fact that zero may not be correct.

Comment: not sure of what you want because if $\epsilon \ne \epsilon'$ fixed the limit is clearly zero, while in the second approach you also get $0$ as long as $\epsilon \ne \epsilon'$ so again not sure what you mean by "Setting $\epsilon =\epsilon'$"; maybe more context would illuminate what you are actually interested in; obviously the integral is $1$ for $\epsilon=\epsilon'$ which corresponds to what you say in the second approach, but why is that relevant in general when $\epsilon \ne \epsilon'$?

Comment: Why does the answer of $0$ "not look correct"?  Intuitively, as long as $\epsilon'\neq\epsilon$, the values of $e^{i(\varepsilon'-\varepsilon)t}$ oscillate around the circle so "average out" to $0$.

Comment: @Conrad I was simply exploring what would happen for different values of $\varepsilon'-\varepsilon$, and checked the obvious case $\varepsilon'-\varepsilon=0$. The context is that there is an integral over $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon'$, so I hoped there would be a $\delta(\varepsilon'-\varepsilon)$ hidden in there.

Comment: @EricWofsey Sure, but I need a general expression also valid for $\varepsilon'-\varepsilon=0$

Comment: the fact that the integral is $0$ when $\epsilon \ne \epsilon'$ and $1$ when they are equal is precisely a delta function, so if you want a general expression, $\delta(\epsilon-\epsilon')$ will do

Comment: @Conrad Shouldn't a delta function evaluate to "infinity" when $\varepsilon=\varepsilon'$?

Comment: no - that is the distribution delta (or if you want the Dirac singular measure) ; the function is $\delta(x)=0, x \ne 0, \delta(0)=1$; these are different things and here the result is the function not the  singular measure

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega = \epsilon - \epsilon '$. Then we wish  to find $\lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T}\int _0^T dt\cdot e^{i\omega t}$

After Integrating: $ \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{-i}{\omega T}(e^{i\omega T}-1)=\frac{e^{i\omega T /2}}{\omega T}(2\sin{\frac{\omega T}{2}})=\frac{\sin {\omega T}}{\omega T}+i\frac{2\sin^2{\omega T /2}}{\omega T}$

If $\omega$ is non-zero, then the denominator dominates and the limit is zero for both the real and imaginary parts. If $\omega$ is zero applications of l'hopital's rule yield 1 for the real part and $0$ for the imaginary part.

So $\lim(...)= \delta(\omega)$